# Remove customer group magento, sql error

Tags: mysql, magento

When i try remove customer group i have sql error

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`nailmania_dev`.`groupswitcher_rules`, CONSTRAINT `FK_gprs_group_id_after` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id_after`) REFERENCES `customer_group` (`customer_group_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCAD), query was: DELETE FROM `customer_group` WHERE (customer_group_id='6')

Please help me

Comment: can i know which extension you used?

Answer (score 0):

There are records in *groupswitcher_rules* that refer to this value in customer_group (i.e. with customer_group = '6'), as your key has ON DELETE NO ACTION InnoDB will reject the DELETE, if it had for example ON DELETE CASCAD it would remove this row and the referring entries from other tables (those with value of '6') and so the DELETE would success.

Now if you don't want to change the behavior, and just need to handle a special case, you could remove manually those entries:

```
DELETE FROM groupswitcher_rules WHERE group_id_after = '6'
```

And now you can try to tun your query to remove the customer group again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I delete  FOREIGN KEY in customer_group table and it help me.

Comment: This isn't necessary the right way to solve the issue, as you have just allowed invalid values for this column, you might have other issues without having constraints.. you could just make it on delete cascad so that when you remove a customer group, its values will be automatically removed from groupswitcher_rules